# Android app freezes instead of getting crash in Jetpack Compose project

Tags: crash, android-jetpack-compose, crashlytics, anr

I implemented crashlytics in my android project. Now wanted to test crash and while I try to crash application by throwing Runtime exception in my compose project instead of crashing UI gets frozen forever.
No ANR nothing just UI freeze.
Anybody having clue why its happening and how it can be fixed.

Update:
Here is code that I'm using to crash app:

```
Button(
        onclick = { 
         throw RuntimeException("issue test")
       }
    ) 
   {
     Text("Crash")
   }
```

Comment: did you opened the logcat to see if its throwing an error and the system UI is not responding in the emulator ?

Comment: show your code?

Comment: Nothing shows up in Logcat no clue just some thing like tap action can not be placed

Comment: @AliNawaz did you found the root cause?
I'm facing a similar problem

Comment: Nope not yet... Kindly do post answer if you find anything suitable.. Also as per my research it looks like it is an issue of any added library. Just as a hint you can go through your last added libraries and comment them one by one and find out the culprit ...

Comment: Can you try to bump the compose runtime to 1.4.0-beta02?

Comment: Can u please specify exact dependency like for compose runtime or do I need to update anything in parent build.gradle which will relate to compose runtime? Also did this solution fixed issue for you?

Comment: Found the problem on my side. It's because of an external dependency "oppwa" that we use for payments.

Comment: yes same is case with me I'm also using it. Any solution you found?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue @extmkv, After adding the 'Oppwa' library app doesn't report any crashes. Could you help with the solution you used to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a specific dependency problem.

A library used in our projects called "Oppwa", used for payments is swallowing all the crashes and sending them to their dashboard.

This isn't just a tech problem but also a legal one in our case.
After contacting the team they have informed they released a new one that removed the interceptor of the crashes.

> Release Notes Version 4.12.0
> Simplified 3D Secure 2.x integration.
>
> SHA-256:
> 9c95a50fcd955312d8a0389ef4d12dee5cb67501da680f3fc468859663cfd71a
>
> Version 4.11.0
> Removed UncaughtException handler internal implementation.
> Updated ipworks_3ds SDK to the version 2.2.8440.
> Updated Klarna Mobile SDK to the version 2.4.0.
> Added support for the following payment method:
> Pay with Klarna (KLARNA_PAYMENTS_ONE)
> Improved ThreeDS2 web flow error handling.
> Changed backend requests timeout configuration to 30 sec.
> General 3D Secure 2.x. improvements and fixes.
> SHA-256:
> 214df7dad1a45ca5334f9b2fdc599244d7faabccf97b1d655940d6bb016f0a59
> Version 4.10.0
> Added support for the following payment methods:
> Ratepay Invoice.
> Ipworks_3ds SDK is updated to the version 2.2.8420.
> Added support for Android version 13 (API level 33).
> Bug fixing and improvements.
> Added option for payment button customization.
> SHA-256:
> f443eb9a99d00d10853294a6d1912924ee07e74c5f3854596b07701bc3eb9b33

Comment: okay so it means we need to contact those guys and ask for newer version of SDK?

Comment: If you use the OPPWA SDK I belive you have somehow access to their dev portal

Comment: I am using HyperPay SDK, and have access to their dashboard which isn't related to development stuff but just for transactions. I've got their SDK directly in mail from their team. May be I've to ask for an updated version of SDK.